# Setting Cookies for JQuery Popup - Popup always opens although cookie is set

Tags: jquery, cookies, popup

I am trying to make a lightbox popup for my website http://www.digitalambiance.co that will open for the user on their first visit to the website and will then not open again.  My thought was to use cookies so I added the jquery.cookie.js script to my overall document. I can get the cookie to register but I cannot make stop the popup from displaying.  I have tried many solutions but I am very new to JQuery so I am thinking I might just be missing something obvious?

Here is my code:

```
//Beginning of function for popup
function(){
  if($.cookie('01012013') != '1'){
        $.cookie('01012013', '1', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        function openOffersDialog() {
            $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $('.overlayp').css('display','inline');
                $('#boxpopup').css('display','block');
                $('#boxpopup').animate({'left':'30%'},500);
            });
        }


    function closeOffersDialog(prospectElementID) {
        $(function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','absolute');
                $('#' + prospectElementID).animate({'left':'-100%'}, 500, function() {
                    $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','fixed');
                    $('#' + prospectElementID).css('left','100%');
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
                });
            });
        });
    }

    } //if statement
  else{
        return;
  }  //else statement
} //overall function statement

//end popup section
```

Thankyou!

Comment: Are you sure the cookie is being set? Check in developer tools > resources > cookies (in Chrome). Also where do you call your openOffersDialog function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked they way you have it on the website. A few things:

- most of the code you pasted is not executable, because the function you have it wrapped around is not called
- however functions declared using the function name() {} construct in JS are **always** created in the global symbol table and they are created regardless of the if or any other statements around them.

i.e.

```
if (false) {
   function x() { }
}
// and 
if (true) {
   function x() { }
}
```

will both create the function x.

What you need to do is first make your code executable by calling the wrapping function you declare, for example:

```
(function () {
    // code
})();
```

Second, don't use onload="" tag since you have jQuery loaded, instead do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { // When the page loads
    if ($.cookie('01012013') != '1') { // Check for cookie
        $.cookie('01012013', '1', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        // Now create your close function
        window.closeOffersDialog = function (prospectElementID) {
            $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','absolute');
            $('#' + prospectElementID).animate({'left':'-100%'}, 500, function() {
                $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','fixed');
                $('#' + prospectElementID).css('left','100%');
                $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
            });
       };
       // and set the timer to open the window
       setTimeout(function () {
           $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
               $('.overlayp').css('display','inline');
               $('#boxpopup').css('display','block');
               $('#boxpopup').animate({'left':'30%'},500);
           });
       }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: So the cookies work great in Firefox and Chrome but do not seem to be working in Safari or IE.  Any suggestions?

Comment: try starting the cookie name with a letter, IE can be crazy like that

Comment: I gave it a try and it did not work.  It does not look like Safari or IE are registering the cookie?  I tried clearing all the browser data, cache, cookies, etc. but it keeps popping up on every page.

Comment: So I realized both of those browsers are setup to automatically block cookies.  I assume it is that way for most users of these browsers.  Is there an additional method I could use to make the popup display only once even if a user has cookies disabled?  Maybe something that is used especially by IE or Safari browsers?

Comment: Blocking cookies is not enabled by default in IE or Safari. You should test on a different computer. Unfortunately this is the only way to "remember" a user.